# jquery ajax post data undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a piece of javascript that uses ajax to get data from my database as such:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getlog',
  data: { id: calEvent.id},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data)
  {
     alert(data[id]);
  }
});
```

If i just alert the 'data' object i get

> [object Object]

The data I am getting back from the ajax request is structured like this:

[image]

I need to be able to get these fields to fill up an edit form (form already exists on my page and I know how to set the values of my edits but I can't access the data)

Comment: Try this data.id or data["id"]

Comment: Thank you data.id did the trick, I tried data[0].id but that didn't work either so I thought I wasn't accurately using the data object, thank you very much

Comment: Try this data.id or alert(data.id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.id` and `data["id"]` both should work. In your case you had `data[id]` so it was trying to search id as a variable which returned undefined.

Comment: That is not an Error, in Js when you alert any object it comes as [object][object]

Comment: I'll accept the answer in 3mins when I can, did this the trick

Comment: @Tushar Gupta : Yes that's correct. but I am saying that data[id] will give you error because javascript will try to search variable id.